# RXTX getPortIdentifiers() stuck

Tags: java, rxtx

I have problem to read lit of serial ports.when programe reach at CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifier()  it stuck for almost 5 minnutes.  as I observe  delay  could be  due to scaning all ports iin system. So how to avoid this 5 minutes delay?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How do you scan for available ports?

For instance, the code below will return string list of available serial ports:

```
public List<String> getAvailablePorts() {

    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    Enumeration portList = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();

    while (portList.hasMoreElements()) {
        CommPortIdentifier portId = (CommPortIdentifier) portList.nextElement();
        if (portId.getPortType() == CommPortIdentifier.PORT_SERIAL) {
            list.add(portId.getName());
        }
    }

    return list;
}
```

**Edit**: since actual solution is digged in comments, I add it here:

It appears that ***commPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifier(portName)*** indeed does port rescan under certain circumstances; fast workaround is to set fixed port list manually via **gnu.io.rxtx.SerialPorts** system property.

Comment: I have fix the port Supoose COM4. but the problem is  on getPortIdentifiers() that take too much time.it works fine in Window Xp but not in vista and window 7

Comment: @Qaiser Mehmood: ah, i see then. AFAIR CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifier(portName) call doesn't do port scanning, it looks more like os-specific issue.

Comment: @Qaiser Mehmood: Well, I was wrong, quick look at rxtx sources reveals that getPortIdentifier() does rescan all ports under some circumstances. Now the question is: does port scanning (like in example above) reveal your "fixed port"? How long does it last?

Comment: I figure out that when I turn On Blutooth addapter it takes time but when I turn OFF bluetooth Addapter it works fine.SO is ther any way that Port scaning ignore bluetooth port.

Comment: @Qaiser Mehmood: try to specify port list explicitly then (this should make rxtx to skip scanning), e.g.: `java -Dgnu.io.rxtx.SerialPorts=COM4 app.java`

Comment: Sorry but I could not Understand  some example or code will be understandable.Thanks

Comment: @Qaiser Mehmood: try running your java application from command line with additional parameter `-Dgnu.io.rxtx.SerialPorts=COMX` (adjust "X" to your actual desired port number), full command would look like `java -Dgnu.io.rxtx.SerialPorts=COM4 -jar your_application.jar`

Comment: @Qaiser Mehmood: you don't have to change anything in your code, this just sets system property `gnu.io.rxtx.SerialPorts` to pre-defined list; if you want to set several ports, use `:` as separator, e.g. `gnu.io.rxtx.SerialPorts=COM1:COM3`

Answer (score 1):

This one may not apply to all circumstances but it works for me and it takes less than a second to get the ports I wanted. I used the devcon utility of Windows basing from the command line.

```
devcon find "usb\vid_067B&PID_2303*"
```

This will list down the ports where the Prolific PL2303 USB-Serial cable is attached. Then I parsed the result. I usually got few results because I only plug one or two cables in my computer.

This code may not be portable and limited but it fits well for my purpose and its speed is way too fast than using CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers().

Here is a part of my code:

```
public List<String> getAvailablePorts() {        
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();        
    String res="";
    BufferedReader br;
    String cmd;
    Process proc;

    try {
        /*search for ports where Prolific PL2303 cable is attached*/
        cmd = "devcon find \"usb\\vid_067B&PID_2303*\"";
        proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);

        /* parse the command line results*/
        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));
        do {
            try {
                res = br.readLine();
                if (res == null)
                    break;

                if (res.contains((CharSequence)("Prolific USB")))
                    list.add(res.substring(res.indexOf("(COM")+1, res.indexOf(")")));
            } catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } while (!res.equals("null"));
        br.close();

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    return list;
}
```

Just make sure the devcon.exe file is correct (32bit or 64bit) and it is in the right folder where the application can access it.

This works on WinXP and Win7/8 64bit but for 32bit Win7/8, the application may need to be launched with administrator rights (run as admin). I added a .manifest file in my final executable so there's no need to "right click and run as admin" on 32bit Windows.

On Ubuntu 14.04 Linux, I used the terminal command

```
ls /dev/ttyUSB*
```

to list down the USB-Serial ports and then parsed the result.